# Is it possible to insert an image without using a filepath src?

Tags: javascript, html, file, src

Assume that I have an image stored as a variable, from a form, in the form of `var someImage = document.getElementById("input1").files[0]`. How would I insert this image saved to a variable into an HTML document, without using filepaths?

Comment: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @AlexK. pointed out the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/FileReader): read file as data URI.

```js
document.getElementById("input1").onchange = function(e) {
  var someImage = e.target.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var img = document.getElementById('preview');
  reader.onload=function(){
    img.src = reader.result
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(someImage)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input1" accept="image/*" />
<img id="preview" src="" />
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a local problem, but when I save your code as an HTML file and then open it from my computer the image does not load. I'm using Firefox (up to date) on an Ubuntu.

Comment: @DevilApple227 code is no porblem on firefox. Can you see any message from browser Console? It's easy to debug.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @DevilApple227 emmm... you should change your element id or something, my code only work for simple example.

Comment: In what sense? Perhaps I'm wrong, but I thought element ids were arbitrary strings, in the sense that it doesn't matter what you set them to?

Comment: sorry I have no idea, you need to debug yourself.